# Como hacer para limitar los valores ingresados en Scanner en java

Tags: java, java-swing, java-util-scanner

Estoy creando un programa en java en el que el usuario ingresa 4 calificaciones de un alumno que son participación, primer examen, segundo examen y examen final. Quiero limitar los valores ingresados del 1 al 10, pero no logro hacerlo. agradecería su ayuda y explicación ya que estoy aprendiendo, gracias!!!

El código hecho es el siguiente:

```
package ejercicio4ats;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio4Ats {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int participacion, pexamen, sexamen, efinal;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese las notas del estudiante");

        Scanner notas = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(notas >0 && notas<=10) {

           notas = participacion.nextInt();
           notas = pexamen.nextInt();
           notas = sexamen.nextInt();
           notas = efinal.nextInt();
        }
        else {

           System.out.println("Fuera de parametros");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `notas`es una instancia de la clase Scanner, no es un número (int, por ejemplo). Debes crear otra variable para guardar el dato leído del teclado. Además necesitarás crear 4 comprobaciones

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para solicitar un parametro al usuario por consola necesitas usar una instancia de la clase Scanner.

```
Scanner esc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Una vez instanciado dicho objeto, este dispone de numerosos metodos que nos permiten solicitar un tipo de dato u otro dependendo de nuestras preferencias. En el siguiente enlace podras encontrar una lista de todos los metodos de los que dispone la clase Scanner.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

En tu caso necesitas invocar el metodo nextInt() si lo que quieres es solicitar un numero entero.

```
nota = esc.nextInt();
```

> Posible Solucion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner esc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int participacion, pexamen, sexamen, efinal;

    System.out.println("Introduzca las siguientes notas");

       System.out.print("Participacion: ");
       participacion = esc.nextInt();
       while(participacion < 0 || participacion > 10){
          System.out.print("Nota de participacion no valida: ");
          participacion = esc.nextInt();
       }

       System.out.print("Primer Examen: ");
       pexamen = esc.nextInt();
       while(pexamen < 0 || pexamen > 10){
          System.out.print("Nota de Primer examen no valida: ");
          pexamen = esc.nextInt();
       }

       System.out.print("Segundo Examen: ");
       sexamen = esc.nextInt();
       while(sexamen < 0 || sexamen > 10){
          System.out.print("Nota de Segundo examen no valida: ");
          sexamen = esc.nextInt();
       }

       System.out.print("Examen Final: ");
       efinal = esc.nextInt();
       while(efinal < 0 || efinal > 10){
          System.out.print("Nota de Examen final no valida: ");
          efinal = esc.nextInt();
       }

    System.out.println("Participacion: " + participacion);
    System.out.println("Primer Examen: " + pexamen);
    System.out.println("Segundo Examen: " + sexamen);
    System.out.println("Examen Final: " + efinal);

}
```

**NOTA**: Logicamente la respuesta esta pensada para que entiendas el funcionamiento de la clase Scanner. No es optima de ninguna forma y el uso de arrays y otras estructuras de control y seleccion reducirian enormemente el codigo.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera, evaluando cada argumento cada vez que introduces notas, es decir, de uno en uno en vez de todos a la vez, cada vez que introduces una nota, si es menor a 0 o mayor que 10, se notifica el mensaje "Fuera de parametros" y el programa finaliza:

```
package ejercicio4ats;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Ejercicio4Ats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int participacion, pexamen, sexamen, efinal;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese las notas del estudiante");
        Scanner notas = new Scanner(System.in);


        participacion = notas.nextInt();
        if(participacion <0 | participacion >10){
            System.out.println("Fuera de parametros");
            //Detenemos la ejecucion del programa:
            System.exit(0);
        }
        pexamen = notas.nextInt();
        if(pexamen <0 | pexamen >10){
            System.out.println("Fuera de parametros");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        sexamen = notas.nextInt();
        if(sexamen <0 | sexamen >10){
            System.out.println("Fuera de parametros");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        efinal = notas.nextInt();
        if(efinal <0 | efinal >10){
            System.out.println("Fuera de parametros");
            System.exit(0);
        }
   }

}
```

Tambien hay que tener en cuenta el uso de "Scanner", ya que el uso correcto sería el siguiente:

```
int participacion, pexamen, sexamen, efinal;
Scanner notas = new Scanner(System.in);

participacion = notas.nextInt();
pexamen = notas.nextInt();
sexamen = notas.nextInt();
efinal = notas.nextInt();
```